# Rails Mocha gem - NoMethodError: undefined method `any_instance'

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, mocha.js

I'm using the Mocha gem in a Rails project to make stubs and bypass some live API calls.

I'm conforming to the [documentation](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) but keep getting an error.

In `Gemfile` (I use Bundler) I have:

```
gem 'minitest'
gem 'minitest-rails'
gem 'mocha', :require => false
```

In `test_helper.rb`:

```
require 'minitest'
require 'mocha/mini_test' # This is the last require statement
```

In `product_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    Product.any_instance.stubs({
      manufacturer: "Acme"
    })
  end

end
```

The output is always `NoMethodError: undefined method 'any_instance' for #<Class:blah>`.

I have another Rails project where I can use `any_instance` successfully, so I've tried resolving by replicating the gems, `require` statements, etc. but with no success. I've also tried different permutations like `require 'minitest/autorun'`, `require "minitest/rails'`, and `require 'mocha/setup'`/`require 'mocha'`, etc.

I'm on Rails 4.1.1 and using MiniTest 5.3.3 and Mocha 1.0.0.

Comment: Have you looked at this link - https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/137